# ASP.NET Core : how to use jwt token to authorize in client side?

Tags: api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I have 2 completely separate projects. The first project is an ASP.NET Core Web API (backend) project and the second project is an ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC (frontend) project.

I want JWT token authentication to be performed after the user enters the information on the login page in frontend.

I can send the `username` and `password` from the frontend to the backend and the token is also generated. But I don't know how to authenticate through this token on the client side.

I use the following function to create a token in the Web API project and the token is generated successfully.

```
    public string BuildToken(string key,string issuer, User user)
    {
        var claims = new[] {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Role),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
        };

        var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
        var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);
        var tokenDescriptor = new JwtSecurityToken(issuer, issuer, claims,
            expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), signingCredentials: credentials);
        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokenDescriptor);
    }
```

and in `program.cs`

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(auth =>
{
   auth.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
      .AddJwtBearer(options =>
      {
          options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
          {
              ValidateIssuer = true,
              ValidateAudience = true,
              ValidateLifetime = true,
              ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
              ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
              ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
              IssuerSigningKey = new 
  SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
      };
  });
```

Comment: The progress of JWT Authentication is:
1. Client authenticates itself with Username and Password to the Server.
2. On successful authentication, the Server creates JWT token and sends it to the client.
3. Client signs the Token with Private key and sends it to the server in HTTP Authorization Header whenever it makes a request to secured resources.
4. Server receives a request, validates the JWT token, and sends secured data to the client. So the validation should happen on the server side not client side. I may ask if you are asking the method how to send the token from client side?

Comment: @XiaotianYang I dont think that the client signs the token - the token must be signed by the issuer (the server) so it can be guaranteed to be a valid token

Comment: @XiaotianYang Thanks, Authentication is done on the server side. But the login operation is not performed on the client side. Do you have an example of this?

Comment: @Nannanas My bad, I made a mistake here. What I meant is that client side should sign the token with public key and the server will test it with private key.

Comment: @topcool you mean you need an example of the login operation which on the server side?

Comment: @XiaotianYang where did you get this from? Any references? The server which issues the token signs it with its private key. That's it. The client does not sign anything. and signing with a public key also makes no sense logically.